# Did anyone find and remove Kiritsugu's explosives?

Tags: fate-stay-night, fate-zero, nasuverse

In [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/13915/1587), I pointed out how Kiritsugu planned to use dynamite and the ley-lines to stop the Holy Grail War from occurring again. However, the plan failed because there was an excess amount of Prana in the Grail which caused the next Holy Grail War to occur earlier.

Given that regardless of the ending, the Greater Grail would be stopped (either by the events of Heaven's Feel, or Lord El-Melloi II and Rin dismantling it 10 years later), what happened to Kiritsugu's explosives?

All [Wikia](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Fuyuki_Holy_Grail_War#Fourth_Holy_Grail_War) says is

> The premature occurrence of the Fifth Holy Grail War and the subsequent destruction of the ritual means that it no longer has a purpose.

Yet it also said

> The process involved utilizing stocked dynamite and the manipulation of ley-lines to ensure a severe localized earthquake in the targeted area within thirty to forty years of the Fourth War

I'm not sure how big the localized earthquake would be, but since the targeted area would be where the Greater Grail is, and it is under Mount Enzou which according to the [Wikia](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Fuyuki#Mount_Enzou) is where Ryuudou Temple is and doesn't look all that far from the school [according to a Fate/Hollow Ataraxia map](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/typemoon/images/a/a8/Fuyuki.png/revision/latest?cb=20111010011339)

So did anyone find and remove Kiritsugu's explosives? If not, do we know if they pose a threat to Fuyuki?

Answer (score 1):

According to Fate Complete Material III: World Material - Record of Heavens Feel - Holy Grail War: History of the Holy Grail War, p.007

> 2010s - The taking apart of the Holy Grail War.
>   Ten years after the Fifth War. Lord Emelloi II (real name, Waver Velvet. One of the Masters of the Fourth War) arrived in Fuyuki and together with the head of the Tohsaka line, set out to completely take apart the Great Grail. The Association was planning on bring back the Greater Grail, so the two sides were completely opposed. After the end of the great turmoil of the same magnitude as the Grail War, the Greater Grail was completely dismantled. The Grail Wars of Fuyuki came to a complete conclusion here.

Since the Greater Grail is connected to the leylines, a thorough analysis of them would take place before dismantling. Remember that Waver was able to locate a Caster servant's lair as a teenager, he should be able to discover whatever Kiritusugu set there, this is just speculation though. At the very least, the meddling with the leylines should be taken care of, but I don't think there's any mention anywhere about the explosives' fate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the explosives were there waiting to explode. It is crazy to think he would set up explosives to explode decades into the future. There is too much risk associated with that. Even if you ingore that most explosives don't have shelf life that long.

Instead he used the explosives at that time to change structure of the caverns and the flow of the ley-lines so that accumulated prana itself would cause the earthquake and destruction of the grail.